# Controlling DB Security Group Port Access via Cloud Formation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a security group that meets the following criteria:

A security group called WordpressDbSecurityGroup which allows incoming access on the standard MySQL port from the WebServerSecurityGroup

Below is how the WordPressDbSecurityGroup and and WebServerSecurityGroup. When I go to build the stack, I get the following error:

"Encountered unsupported property FromPort"

Can someone please explain why? I can't find anything in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-security-group-ingress.html) about how to specify access from the port for the dbsecurity group.

```
        "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
            },
            "GroupDescription": "Allow access from HTTP and SSH traffic",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "3306",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "22",
                    "ToPort": "22",
                    "CidrIp": {
                        "Ref": "YourIp"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },

        "wordpressDBSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "EC2VpcId": {
                "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
            },
            "GroupDescription": "Enable access to the db via port 3306.",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "wordpressDBSecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "DBSecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "TCP",
                    "FromPort": "3306",
                    "ToPort": "3306",
                    "SourceSecurityGroupID" : {"Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup"}
                }
            ]
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "WebServerSecurityGroup"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup` is only for **EC2-classic**, which is when you have RDS from before 2013. These days you don't use it as all new RDS will be in a VPC, not EC2-classic.

Thus, you should be using regular [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html) for your RDS DB instance. Then you reference it in [VPCSecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-vpcsecuritygroups) of your `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the security group by using REF but got an error. That: 



 "Value of property VPCSecurityGroups must be of type List of String"



"VPCSecurityGroups" : {"Ref": "wordpressDBSecurityGroup"},

Comment: @redwytnblak The error msg says it all. Yo must use list of strings, not a string only.